# Angular Chart ignore scroll page behaviour

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I'm using angular-chart (http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to make a single page application with differents chart.
The page could be scrolled to see all charts.

I had a problem with the behaviour of the browser after data refreshing (using asynchronous call to restfull services): the page is scrolled up or down automatically, depending on the "last" response obtained from the services.

My aim is: 
- if I am in the middle on the page, I want to stay on the middle of the page
- if I am in the top on the page, I want to stay on the top of the page
- if I am in the bottom on the page, I want to stay on the bottom of the page.

Can someone suggest me any solution to avoid this scrolling (to disable/ignore this scrolling)?